# File Access Times in Windows + NTFS

Tags: windows, winapi, file, filesystems, ntfs

I am trying to figure out when and how does Windows update File Access Times on files.
First of all, most Windows installs come with File Access Times disabled for performance reasons, so before wrapping your head around it here is what you need to do in order to activate last access times on NTFS file systems: modify the key `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]` value name `NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate` to DWORD `0` value data(if it is set to 1 of course). If it doesn't exist just create it.

Upon reading [File Times article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN i am still in doubt as to how Windows updates access times.

My questions are as follow:

- Do access times update upon issuing a WinApi `CreateFile()` with `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` ? In my case, while doing it programmatically, it doesn't. Opening up the File Properties dialog of that file through the Explorer Shell does update the access time.
- Do access times update upon issuing a WinApi `ExtractIconEx()` to read an icon from a file?
  In my case doing so programatically, it doesn't. Opening up the File Properties dialog of that file through the Explorer Shell does update the access time.

If you ask me, both of those cases should update the file access times, but it seems to me that direct WinApi calls don't update them or Window/NTFS driver really lags behind, while operating on files from Windows Explorer do update pretty well. What do you think is or could be the issue here?

As a side note, i **did** do `CloseHandle()` as per:

> The only guarantee about a file
>   timestamp is that the file time is
>   correctly reflected when the handle
>   that makes the change is closed.

My end conclusion is that, indeed the opinions lying around the web are true and Windows does update File Access Times in a random fashion and thus one really shouldn't in no way depend on Windows File Access Times.

Off-topic rant: Sorry forensics guys, you'll have to prove access times using another method or you can have your case invalided in seconds. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, accessing the metadata of the file isn't going to change the last access time (name, attributes, timestamps).  Wouldn't work well in practice, just looking at the directory with Explorer would change it.  You have to actually open the file.  ExtractIconEx() would normally be an excellent candidate, except that Windows can play tricks with it.  A hidden desktop.ini file can redirect the icon to another file.

Using the last access time is pretty worthless for forensics.  You'd need a file system filter driver.  Similar to the one embedded in SysInternals' ProcMon utility.  It might be using ETW btw, that got pretty powerful at Vista time.  Nevertheless, your project just got 10 times more complicated.

Comment: However issuing File->Properties from Explorer do change the last access times, is it because it grabs the icons? What about files which don't embed their own icons and are assigned one by default by the OS based on the extension, they do get their access times updated. There must be some other kind of info that the Explorer tries to grab from the file, if it's not the file properties/metadata?

Comment: Why don't you use SysInternals' ProcMon?  It shows you exactly what kind of file accesses take place.

Comment: Already did that and it accesses a lot of things. Gets pretty hard to track at one point, especially embedded(ShellEx) actions in the explorer, since we are not talking about a separate process. I'll get back with results once i do get to a conclusion.